# Python connect to 000webhost web server MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to connect Python to a web server's database, 000webhost I am using. Here is my code:

```
import MySQLdb
>>> conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="mysql9.000webhost.com",user="user_name",passwd="password",db="db_name")
```

I think I install MySQLdb successfully. And all the username, password, host, database name are exactly the same as they are in my php file, which works perfectly. However, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="mysql9.000webhost.com",user="a6969519_123",passwd="lianshiyu08",db="a6969519_shiyu")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql9.000webhost.com' (60)")
```

What did I miss?

Comment: You missed changing your username and password in the error message, so you may want to change that.

Comment: your user is probably created tha way that it can connect only from localhost

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson  thanks for reminding. There is nothing important there anyway.

Comment: @FlashThunder So how should I write the code if I want to connect python to a web server? I google it, this way is kind of the only way I can find.

Comment: It's not about the code, but about MySQL server configuroation... you got to add there user `user@ip_that_you_are_connecting_from` or `user@%` to accept connections from all hosts (dangerous)

Answer (score 1):

The database is only reachable from the internal web of your hoster.

Comment: So how can I connect python with my database? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ShiyuLian it won't be possible unless you move to paid hosting